# Tableview Like Snapchat Send Feature (Multiple Selection and Swipeable Label)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview, swift3

In my Xcode Project I will like to have a similar view like Snapchat's "Send To..." screen (I have attached a screenshot). I have already made a tableview and populate it and have allowed multiple selection on. I am currently having trouble with two things:

**1) Multiple Selection:** I can select an cell I want, but when I tap on the search bar and start typing, all my previous selections go away. I am assuming that I need to add all of the names in a array and somehow communicate the array with the table so it shows if this username is in the array then make it selected in the tableview. But I am not sure how to do that. ***How can I do this?***

**2) Sending to Bottom Bar (blue in photo):** As you may know, in Snapchat as you press on which users you want to send the snap to, their names get added to the bar at the bottom, as you fill up the bar, it because swipe able where you can horizontally scroll through the names you have added. I can append the names to an array and show the array in a label like theirs, but I do not know how to make it so a user can horizontally scroll through it.***How do I implement this same feature?***

Feel free to answer ANY of the questions! You do not need to do all of them, I just need them answered. Here's my code so far:

```
class User {        
        var userID:String?
        var userFullName:String?
        var userUsername:String?
        var userProfileImage:PFFile?
        var isPrivate:Bool

        init(userID : String, userFullName : String, userUserName : String, userProfileImage : PFFile, isPrivate : Bool) {
            self.userID = userID
            self.userFullName = userFullName
            self.userUsername = userUserName
            self.userProfileImage = userProfileImage
            self.isPrivate = isPrivate
        }
    }

var userArray = [User]()
    func loadFriends() {
            //STEP 1: Find friends
            let friendsQuery = PFQuery(className: "Friends") //choosing class
            friendsQuery.whereKey("friendOne", equalTo: PFUser.current()?.objectId ?? String()) //finding friends
            friendsQuery.limit = self.page //number of users intitally showing
            friendsQuery.findObjectsInBackground (block: { (objects, error) -> Void in
                if error == nil { //if no error

                    //clean up
                    self.friendsArray.removeAll(keepingCapacity: false)

                    //STEP 2: Find related objects depending on query setting
                    for object in objects! {
                        self.friendsArray.append(object.value(forKey: "friendTwo") as! String) //hold array info of friend
                    }

                    //STEP 3: Find friend info
                    let query = PFUser.query()
                    query?.whereKey("objectId", containedIn: self.friendsArray) 
                    query?.addDescendingOrder("createdAt") //how to order users
                    query?.findObjectsInBackground(block: { (objects, error) -> Void in
                        if error == nil {

                            for object in objects! {                            
                                var user : User

                            let fullname = (object.value(forKey: "fullname") as! String)
                            let username = (object.object(forKey: "username") as! String)
                            let profilePhoto = (object.object(forKey: "profilePhoto") as! PFFile)
                            let objectID = (object.objectId!)
                            let isPrivate = (object.object(forKey: "isPrivate") as! Bool)

                            user = User(userID: objectID, userFullName: fullname, userUserName: username, userProfileImage: profilePhoto, isPrivate: isPrivate)
                            self.userArray.append(user)
                            }
                            self.tableView.reloadData()
                        } else {
                            print(error!)
                        }
                    })
                } else {
                    print(error!)
                }
            })
        }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell") as! FriendCell
            let user = userArray[indexPath.row]

        //add user info to cells
        cell.fullnameLabel.text = user.userFullName
        cell.usernameLabel.text = user.userUsername
        cell.objectID = user.userID!
        cell.isPrivate = user.isPrivate
        user.userProfileImage?.getDataInBackground (block: { (data, error) in
            if error == nil {
                cell.profilePhoto.image = UIImage(data: data!)
            }             
        })                
                })
    }
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1) Multiple Selection:**
You should have a User class (e.g User) that holds user properties instead of maintaining `array` for each property. Store User object in a `Array`. User class could be like below:

```
    class User {

    var userID:String
    var userFullName:String
    var userName:String
    var userProfileImageUrl:String

    init(userID:String,userFullName:String,userName:String,userProfileImageUrl:String) {
        self.userID = userID
        self.userFullName = userFullName
        self.userName = userName
        self.userProfileImageUrl = userProfileImageUrl
    }
}
```

You could have a User extension to check if that user is selected or not(e.g isSelected).

```
import UIKit
import Foundation

private var selectedKey: UInt8 = 0
extension User {
    var isSelected:Bool{
        get {
            return objc_getAssociatedObject(self, &selectedKey) as! Bool
        }
        set {
            objc_setAssociatedObject(self, &selectedKey, newValue, .OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN_NONATOMIC)
        }
    }
}
```

Now in your `func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell` check that `user.isSelected == true/false` and update your selected/deselected image accordingly.
And update the value of `isSelected` in `func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)`

**2) Sending to Bottom Bar:**
For bottom bar add a `UICollectionView` as a subview in `UIView`. Create a class overriding `UICollectionViewCell` that holds a `UILabel`. You can add `flow layout` in `UICollectionView`.

I have given just an idea to start with.Hope it will help you.

Comment: How do I use a user class exactly? I am a novice coder and have not used this before. I have already enter ur `class User...` in the code but when I go to my `loadfriends()` function I can not add any of the objects to the class

Comment: As i have said, I have just given you an idea to start with. If it is helpful to you than you should accept  my answer so that i can help you further.

Comment: I have accepted your answer and would like to have your help. How do I add the data I receive from my `loadFriends()` function?

Comment: I have updated my answer also. And you can try like this: `for object in objects! {
    var user:User = User(object.objectId!,object.value(forKey: "fullname") as! String,object.object(forKey: "username") as! String,object.object(forKey: "profilePhoto") as! String)
    self.userArray.append(user)`
    }

Comment: Ah I have implemented your code and the tableview loads my users. I am about to try the multiple selection and I will get back to you. But in the meantime, I will like to organize my users alphabetically by their full name. How is this possible with a class?

Comment: My extension User is not working. I added to the bottom of my view controller after the User class and I am receiving the error "Extensions may not contain stored properties". How should I fix this?

Comment: Hey i have updated my answer. Sorry for the extension :p

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152568/discussion-between-fphelp-and-torongo).

Comment: I have implemented your updated code and in my `cellForRowAt` function I have added: `if user.isSelected == true { 
cell.isSelected = true 
} else { 
cell.isSelected = false 
}` But when I try to load the tableview I receive an error and it highlights "return objc_getAssociatedObject(self, &selectedKey) as! Bool" The error in the console is "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value". What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I think, you set bool check for every cell in tableView. If cell load again, it will not show check. Because, It check is false.